# Alguém pode me explicar esta lógica no WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Bom vi esta lógica em tema de WordPress desenvolvido por um colega, e lá havia a seguinte lógica:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $post_type = new WP_Query( 'post_type=cpt' );
    if ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
            $post_type->the_post();
            if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) : ?>
                <div class="post-de-um-jeito" ></div> <?php
            else: ?>
                <div class="post-de-outro-jeito"></div> <?php
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Sei que a lógica é simples, porém eu sou novo no PHP, e nunca vi isso no WordPress. Obrigado!

Comment: o operador módulo `%` retorna o resto da divisão inteira, logo o código exibe as `<div>`s pares de um jeito e impares de outro.

Comment: Pega posts do tipo `cpt`; Se tem posts; Enquanto tem posts; Printa o post; Se o post for *par* printa `div.post-de-um-jeito` se não printa `div.post-de-outro-jeito`... +- isso ?

Comment: Entendi... Muito bom galera obrigado pela força :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta lógica também faz parte do PHP, porém a diferença no Wordpress é que ele criou seus próprios métodos para cada ação com o banco de dados, usando uma classe:

```
    <?php
        //declara a variável $i como 0 para no while ele trazer a função de mod que explicarei abaixo
        $i = 0;
        /* Cria uma instância da classe de Querys do Wordpress,
           passando para o método construtor o parâmetro da consulta,
           que no caso é post_type=cpt, siginifica que o tipo
           "custom post type" (tipo de post customizado) */
        $post_type = new WP_Query( 'post_type=cpt' );
        //Então ele verifica se o método "have_posts()" possui algum post
        if ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
            //Se ele retornar "true", ele faz um laço do tipo "while" no objeto para listar cada valor retornado 
            while ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
 // aqui ele executa o método "the_post()", que internamente tem toda a estrutura da publicação, como título, texto, data etc.
                $post_type->the_post();
                //Aqui ele pega o resto da divisão de $i por 2, caso seja igual a 0, ele exibe abaixo do post uma estrutura de um jeito, caso contrário de outro jeito.
                if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) : ?>
                    <div class="post-de-um-jeito" ></div> <?php
                else: ?>
                    <div class="post-de-outro-jeito"></div> <?php
                endif;
              //aqui deveria ter um $i++;
            endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
```

Basicamente essa estrutura se repete alternando o rodapé de cada publicação para cada post que é exibido no laço. Porém acredito que para essa regra com o `$i` funcionar deveria ter logo abaixo, antes do `endwhile` um incrementador:  `$i++`;

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei o código comentado:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    //Faz uma consulta dos posts, recebendo o parametro post_type, que pega os posts do tipo cpt
    $post_type = new WP_Query( 'post_type=cpt' );
    //Verifica se encontrou posts
    if ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
        //Fz um loop nos posts
        while ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
            $post_type->the_post();
            //Veirica o resto da divisão de $i por 2
            if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) : ?>
                <div class="post-de-um-jeito" ></div> <?php
            else: ?>
                <div class="post-de-outro-jeito"></div> <?php
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Porem pelo que eu entendi desse código ele queria intercalar os post com numero impar e par usando o `counter` `$i`, porem ele não está incrementando essa variável. No caso `$i` vai ser sempre 0 e sempre vai entrar no `if ( $i % 2 == 0 )`.